# How to improve performance of SyncReplicaFromAllServers (ActiveDirectory)

Tags: performance, active-directory, replication

I'm calling `SyncReplicaFromAllServers` and it takes between 30 and 60 seconds for the method to complete, even when the DC's are in the same site.

Are there any settings could be used to improve the time it takes?

I'm currently doing this, while registering against the `SyncFromAllServersCallback` to pickup exceptions:

```
controller.SyncReplicaFromAllServers(partition, SyncFromAllServersOptions.AbortIfServerUnavailable | SyncFromAllServersOptions.SkipInitialCheck);
```

Comment: Hmm, why are you calling this in the first place? (not questioning the goal so much as the method :) context would help...)

Comment: I have a Windows service that maintains AD information in a multi-AD-server environment.  I am looking for options to include that would perform the fastest, same site synchronization of AD data between Domain Controllers (DC).